# Showing that this is a biholomorphism.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am supposed to prove that:

> $f(z)=\frac{-1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$ is a biholomorphism from the upper
>   unit disc: $\{z : |z|<1, \Im(z)>0\}$, to the upper half plane $\{z:
> > \newcommand{Im}{\operatorname{Im}} \Im(z) >0\}$

From an earlier theorem, I only need since f is a holomorphic, to show that it is a **bijection**. I am struggling with the surjectivity. I have shown that it maps to the upper half plane and that it is one-to one. But the surjectivity I am struggling with. Here is my work:

**Need to show that it maps to the upper half plane:**

If $z=x+iy$, we have:
$f(z)=\frac{-1}{2}(x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+iy(1-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}))$. Since $x^2+y^2< 1$, and $y>0$ since we hare in the upper unit disc, we see that this maps to the upper half plane.

**one to one:**

$\frac{-1}{2}(z_1+\frac{1}{z_1})=\frac{-1}{2}(z_2+\frac{1}{z_2}) \rightarrow$

$z_1z_2+z_2=z_2z_1+z_1\rightarrow z_1=z_2$

**surjectivity?**

I tried something like this:
Let w be in the upper half plane. Then

$w = \frac{-1}{2}(z+1/z)\rightarrow z^2+2wz+1=0$. Now I get a an equation that I can solve, I get the solutions $-w +\sqrt{w^2-1}$. Where the square-root is multivalued(it should be plus minus). But I need to in some way show that I get back in the upper unit disc?